# VS Installer Solution warning errors: 'DLL file is under Windows System File Protection' during Compile

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, compiler-warnings, vs-installer-project

I'm **building** an **Installer Solution** for a VS project in C#.
During the compile process I get the following `warnings`:

```
WARNING: 'System.Linq.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Net.Http.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Collections.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Threading.Tasks.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.IO.Compression.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Reflection.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http.WebRequest\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Runtime.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Reflection.Extensions.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Reflection.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Threading.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Text.Encoding.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Text.Encoding\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Text.Encoding.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
WARNING: 'System.IO.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.IO.dll' is under Windows System File Protection.
```

As well as these which I believe are related:

```
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.reflection.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.reflection.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.net.http.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.net.http.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.extensions.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.extensions.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.threading.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.threading.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.diagnostics.debug.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.diagnostics.debug.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.threading.tasks.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.threading.tasks.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.serialization.primitives.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.serialization.primitives.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.io.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.io.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.text.encoding.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.text.encoding.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.io.compression.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.io.compression.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.diagnostics.tracing.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.diagnostics.tracing.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.reflection.extensions.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.reflection.extensions.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.linq.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.linq.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.collections.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.collections.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.dll')
WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.dll')
```

Reading some related posts I beleive I should remove these dll's from the Installer itself, meaning from the Primary Output of the Installer Solution...? Is this correct or is the issue somewhere else?

A further question is - will this harm any functionality on a user's machine? Do all of these dll's exist on standard Windows and will work without being compiled?

Thank you

Comment: Those related questions don't seem to be related, at least I can't find any mentions of VS Installer Deployment Projects which this is about. I received three separate errors about different DLLs, and I noticed they have duplicate entries in the Setup.vdproj file. I reduced them down to one each, and made sure the Exclude property is set to true, but the same errors still show up. Going a little crazy over here.

Comment: Update: despite removing any trace of the offending libraries from my setup project file, I still receive the errors. I also noticed that Visual Studio was automatically marking those same files to be included despite me marking them as excluded. I think there's something about the Installer Project compiler that's forcing these libraries to be included. This has led me to discover just how old this system is (2010 or older), and the _best_ solution is likely finding newer deployment software. I'm considering WiX and ClickOnce.